# How to stream MacOS desktop screen over local IP using ffmpeg or python or objective-C or Swift?

Tags: python, swift, objective-c, macos, ffmpeg

I am trying to build a service/application/script on MacBook that can help me share my desktop screen [Mirror my screen] over a local IP address.

Or I want to display it on a webpage using flask framework using python.

I just wish to look at my desktop screen along with the mouse movements on a web-browser, just like a Remote Desktop.

I did try the following command, but when I try to open my browser and go to the IP address it just shows a blank screen

```
sudo ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -pix_fmt uyvy422 -i "0" -listen 1 -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency  "http://localhost:8000"
```

Please kindly help!!

Answer (score 0):

use WebRTC?
no usr WebRTCCamera only use datachannel

Comment: Any reference links? it would be helpful to me. Thank you.